# two way binding between view and service in angular2

Tags: angular, data-binding, service

I have 2 components in my app.

first and second component are both injected to the app.component.
In the first component i have a dropdown and when the option is selected the data in the second component must be updated.
For this i'm using a service.

So when the change event of the first compoenent's select is fired i make the array empty in the service and load fresh data

```
public setDataByCategory() {
        console.log("CURRENT ROUTE=====" + this.route.url);
        var isBookmarked = false;
        if (this.route.url == '/test') {
            isBookmarked = false;
        }
        else {
            isBookmarked = true;
        }
        this.dataArray.length = 0;//=> EMPTY THE ARRAY
        this.getCompanyData('', isBookmarked, true).then(data => {

            this.setData(data);
        });

    }



public setData(data: any) {
        var datas= data.datas;
        for (let i in datas) {
            var current = this.formatdata(datas[i]);
            this.dataArray.push(current );

        }



    }
```

when i empty the dataArray by using
 **this.dataArray.length = 0;**
the view gets updated.
But when i insert the new value using **this.setData(data);** the view doesnt change.I dont understand why this kind of behaviour .
We can use observables to achieve this change but why deletion works but adding data doesnt.

I need some understanding on this.

Comment: This is cause current in the end is in a sevice call. A service call is **Async** so you have to import `import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';` . And then in HTML `*ngFor="let item of dataArray | async"`

Comment: @Swoox: InvalidPipeArgument error

Comment: did u logged the array after setting data using `setData` ? it contains data ?

Comment: A wait it's a promise check https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe . You can do it with the old Async `{{item?.name}}`.

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid: Yes the array  has data.

Comment: can you please edit the post by adding the content of the method `formatdata` and your HTML template ?